# How to print the file name in a folder in mac terminal by the order of the order which shows in the graphic window?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Update:
I do as the comment say change locale `LC_COLLATE` from `zh_CN.UTF-8` to `en_US.UTF-8` but it seems don't work.

[05~07_11-06-49.png http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~07_11-06-49.png](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~07_11-06-49.png)

`ls -1` doesn't work 
[05~07_11-05-51.png http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~07_11-05-51.png](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~07_11-05-51.png)

I use the followed bash code on my mac:

```
for file in *
do 
echo $file 
done
```

The order doesn't match the order in the `graphic` window, so how can I print the file name in the order as the graphic window shows ?

Like the pic below

***Graphic window order*** use the default order **none** here :
`1.txt a.txt order.sh Ub.tx`

***Terminal Order :***
`1.txt Ub.tx a.txt order.sh`

[05~06_12-53-21.png http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~06_12-53-21.png](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~06_12-53-21.png)

Comment: What "graphic window"? Finder? Do you have the files in Finder sorted by some sort method?

Comment: Does `locale` report `LC_COLLATE=C`? Does setting `LC_COLLATE` to some other value (whatever `LANG` is set to assuming it is something *other* than `C`) help?

Comment: the res of the `locale` of the LC_COLLATE is `zh_CN.UTF-8`

Comment: And does running `LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8; for file in *; do echo "$file"; done` return the files in the order you want?

Comment: @EtanReisner thx but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it change the order at all? Does `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8; for ....` get the order you want?

Comment: does a simple `ls -1` give you what you want? (that is a -one not -el, and means to output each file on a separate line)

Comment: Yeah I tried both `zh_CN` and `en_US`, neither worked in my mac.

Comment: @Cwissy No, `ls -1` doesn't work here. tnx anyway. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing may be a culture clash between OS X's classic Mac OS heritage on the one hand, and its BSD Unix heritage on the other hand, which was adopted later:

- The OS X Finder sorts filenames case-*INsensitively*.
- The Unix `ls` utility and Bash's pathname expansion (globbing; e.g., `*`) sort filenames
  case-*SENSITIVELY*  -  which is typical on Unix-like systems.

Given that the default OS X filesystem - [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) - is case-*INsensitive*, the Finder's behavior makes sense.

**Update**: The OP has discovered that **the techniques below only *approximate* Finder's behavior**, because **Finder applies additional sorting logic** with filenames containing *numbers*: **embedded sequences of (decimal) digits - regardless of position - are sorted *numerically***.
There are no `ls` or `sort` options that would provide the same behavior generically in the terminal.<sup>Do let me know if you know of a way.</sup>

<sup>The following command creates test files whose names have embedded numbers; compare the output in terminal with the ordering in Finder, which will differ:

`touch {1,2,10}.txt a{1,2,10}.txt {1,2,10}z.txt «{1,2,10}».txt; ls -1f`;

for instance, in the terminal you'll see `1.txt 10.txt 2.txt` (purely *lexical* sorting), whereas Finder will show them ordered as `1.txt 2.txt 10.txt` (*numeric* sorting applied to the embedded number).</sup>

---

To get `ls` to behave as Finder does, add the `-f` option - `ls -f` - but note that this invariably also outputs hidden (`.`-prefixed) files, including `.` and `..`; to compensate for that, you could use `grep`:

```
 ls -f | grep -v '^\.'  # lists filenames sorted case-insensitively, with no hidden files
```

Note that the true purpose of `ls`'s `-f` option is to *suppress* sorting, which means that it's up to the *system* in what order the files are listed.
On OS X, you *happen* to get case-insensitive ordering, but that's not true of all platforms; e.g., on Ubuntu with an ext4 filesystem, no particular order is guaranteed.

---

For *globbing* with `*`, by contrast, there's no direct fix, but you can use the approach from [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084159/45375):

```
printf '%s\n' * | sort -f
```

`sort`'s `-f` option performs case-insensitive sorting.

To use this robustly in a loop, a carefully constructed `while` loop in lieu of `for` is needed:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  echo "$file"
done < <(printf '%s\n' * | sort -f)
```

On the off chance that you need to deal with filenames with *embedded newlines*, use the following variation:

```
while IFS= read -d '' file; do
  echo "$file"
done < <(printf '%s\0' * | sort -f)
```

Comment: if the file name contains just [a-zA-z]  `ls | sort -f` work fine. But if the folder contains `1.txt 2.txt 11.txt` terminal shows `1.txt 11.txt 2.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this--it works on OS X for me and will do the same thing on any *nix:

```
ls | sort -f
```

That is, sort aA-zZ, alphabetical ignoring case.  That seems to be what OS X Finder does.

This does something similar, but the output is slightly different and it shows "hidden" dotfiles by default:

```
find . -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: One more question plz how did you find the default sort order in the `finder`? Guess according to the file sort in your folder ?

Comment: Nicely done; it turns out that `ls -f` also happens to yield case-insensitive sorting _on OS X_, albeit invariably including hidden files, including `.` and `..`.

Comment: @lizhe: You can sort by different file attributes by clicking a column header in Finder, but if you sort by _name_, as is the default, the sort order is _invariably_ case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

ls -l to give the full result.. Copy and paste the result into the excel and sort according to your choice. For e.g. sort by date.